# How to call a second function after the execution of first

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-objects

I have a function `f1(valueOfData)` executing which I can pull data from an external data source. Also, I have another function `f2()` which has an if loop and validates that the value has been pulled before calling a third function.
Having tried lots, I am stuck in a situation where in the second function(data Validation function) is getting called before the execution of `f1(valueOfData)` is complete and the data is pulled(takes a couple of minutes).

I understand that Javascript is event driven and hence tried using the second function(validation function) as a call back but however, I am still unable to achieve it. Also, I am unable to use the `window.setTimeOut(millis)` as I need to calculate the exact time taken to retrieve the data from the database (using `performance.now()`).

```
function call(){
  doc1.validateFilterColumn("columnName");
}

function a(callBack){
  doc1.applyFilter('1-7');
  callBack();
}
 
a(call);
```

Can somebody please help me suggest how to wait for the first function to entirely complete before executing the second.

Comment: Which function is “the first” and which is “the second”?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear about which function is `f1` in your code and which is `f2`? Is `applyFilter()` the `f1` method and `validateFilterColumn` the `f2` function your referring to?

Comment: Please show the real code you have, as this most likely has something to do with asynchronous tasks.

Comment: The functions are: 
 1) The first function is doc1.applybookmark(value): This is an async function that calls an API from where the data is fetched.  I created the function f1() that calls this api.
 2) The second function is the validation function for the value.

Answer (score 0):

By default javascript runs codes sequentially. if you have synchronous functions you can call them like this:

```js
functionA();
functionB();
```

if it was async function you can simply use async await format:

```js
async function A(){
await functionB();
await functionC();
.
.
.
}
```

or you can define callback function right after finishing the first one.

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
async function f1(){
  let something = await processYouWantToWait()
  f2()
}
```